# References to different tables

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have a notifications list, and these notifications MAY implicitly reference a row from table B, or table C or etc (so that selecting that nofication in a client app would result in fetching a different result).

The ad-hoc solution was to create a notifications table and add nullable columns for every possible reference type, which feels wrong.

Another ad-hoc solution returns the same table with nullables during query, but leaves the notifications tables clean.

```
DECLARE @tmpF TABLE(id INT)
DECLARE @tmpA TABLE(two CHAR(1), f_id INT)
DECLARE @tmpB TABLE(three DECIMAL(5, 2), f_id INT)

-- 6 bases
INSERT INTO @tmpF (id) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6)
-- 3 A-s
INSERT INTO @tmpA (f_id, two) VALUES (2, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (4, 'c')
-- 2 B-s (a base can live by itself)
INSERT INTO @tmpB (f_id, three) VALUES (5, 3.14), (1, 2.17), (5, 5.123)

-- Results in the same table with nullable columns
SELECT f.id, two, three
FROM @tmpF AS f
  LEFT JOIN @tmpA a ON f.id = a.f_id
  LEFT JOIN @tmpB b ON f.id = b.f_id
```

What would be some better strategy to model it? Or should try and not model this at all? Like having the client parse some notifications content  to find what should load (which is making up some parsing code, so hence being interesting in a database solution)

Comment: Not sure if it is a good option: each notification could store both "notification source table name" (varchar), "notification reference record identifier" (the PK(s) in the referenced table) and notification reference columns. The client can dynamically create a query to fetch the information. E.g. `SELECT columns FROM table where PkColId = @PkValue`.